# Python + Numpy: When is it useful to manually collect garbage?

Tags: python, numpy, garbage-collection, scipy

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python) that one could manually collect garbage using

```
gc.collect()
```

Now I'm wondering when it is useful to do so. I suppose it is to some extent general Python logic. Say I have a large loop and in each loop will use big matrices `Z` and rewrite them again and again. Is it useful to remove the matrices and collect garbage in the end, if I don't change the size of `Z`?

**The general question** Under which circumstances can one actually observe the impact of forced garbage collection, especially when doing lots of numerical computation within `numpy`?

Comment: This is nearly a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977904/how-to-implement-garbage-collection-in-numpy

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the answers in the comment, the simplest way to release memory is `del array` and let the garbage collector do its job.