# Why Jupyter Notebook consumes more and more data as I load a dataset into the same variable several times?

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm simply loading a CSV data inside jupyter-lab as follows:

```py
data = pd.read_csv('data_simple.csv')
```

The file is around 300 MB. So when I load it, the memory usage increases significantly; let's say 500 MB. That's okay.

But when I run the exact same cell again, memory usage increases as much as the first time. And it keeps going as I run the same cell.

Why this happens? I'm loading it into the same variable: `data`. Shouldn't it just free the old data and re-assign it? Where the old data goes if it just keeps all the data in the memory? I have tried to Google it but couldn't find anything except [this](https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues/1821). Thanks.

Comment: The answer is in the very link you posted in the question. The notebook stores all output of the executed cells in the Out[n]. So if you run a cell once, the result will be stored in the Out[1], if you run in another time, the second result will be in the Out[2].

Comment: I thought that's because of the library `holoviews`. Do you know how to make jupyter to not to do that, if I assign to the same variable?

Comment: I believe there was a keyboard shortcut for it,  but [this question might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816237/ipython-notebook-clear-cell-output-in-code)

Comment: Do you mean just right clicking and `clear outputs` would work? Because it didn't.

Comment: In [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261240/releasing-memory-of-huge-numpy-array-in-ipython) there are described ways to clear the Out output array. Those should work. I don't have access to jupyter right now so I can't try them now.